# Standard deviation if in Excel

Tags: standard-deviation, excel

I have three variables some of which are occasionally 0 which is a na and not a sample. I would like to calculate the standard deviation of the remaining two items but there isn't a deviation if like there is an averageif does anyone know how to do an STDEVIF?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting 0 samples to `""`, I was able to do `=if(count(range)>1,stdev(range),"")`.